# how to edit a specific column of a file and keep the same the other parts of it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to edit "mass" column under [ atoms ] part of a file and I want to keep the same the other parts of it. I need to multiply each mass by 3 but I get the following error when typed "./test.py input.top > output.top" command. How should I fix that error?

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./test.py", line 36,
>   in 
>       sys.exit(main(sys.argv))   File "./test.py", line 19, in main
>       mass = atom.split()[7] IndexError: list index out of range

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main(argv):

    itp = open(argv[1])

    line = itp.readline()

    while line:
        print(line, end="")
        if line.startswith('[ atoms ]'):
            break
        line = itp.readline()

    atom = []
    for atom in line:
        if atom:
            mass = atom.split()[7]
            atom = atom.replace(
                '{:>8}'.format(mass),
                '{:8.5f}'.format(float(mass) * 3)
            )
            print(atom.rstrip(), '; edited')
        else:
            print(atom, end="")

    print("\n", itp.read(), sep="")

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

**Input file:**

```
[ atomtypes ]
;name   bond_type     mass     charge   ptype   sigma         epsilon       Amb
 c3       c3          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.39967e-01   4.57730e-01 ; 1.91  0.1094
 n3       n3          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.25000e-01   7.11280e-01 ; 1.82  0.1700
 h1       h1          0.00000  0.00000   A     2.47135e-01   6.56888e-02 ; 1.39  0.0157
 hn       hn          0.00000  0.00000   A     1.06908e-01   6.56888e-02 ; 0.60  0.0157

[ moleculetype ]
;name            nrexcl
 MOL              3

[ atoms ]
;   nr  type  resi  res  atom  cgnr     charge      mass       ; qtot   bond_type
     1   c3     1   MOL    C1    1     0.152200     12.01000 ; qtot 0.152
     2   n3     1   MOL    N1    2    -0.723601     14.01000 ; qtot -0.571
     3   c3     1   MOL    C2    3     0.163500     12.01000 ; qtot -0.408
     4   c3     1   MOL    C3    4     0.161900     12.01000 ; qtot -0.246
     5   n3     1   MOL    N2    5    -0.820001     14.01000 ; qtot -1.066
[ bonds ]
;   ai     aj funct   r             k
     1      2   1    1.4700e-01    2.6828e+05 ;     C1 - N1    
     1      8   1    1.0930e-01    2.8108e+05 ;     C1 - H1    
     1      9   1    1.0930e-01    2.8108e+05 ;     C1 - H2    
     1     10   1    1.0930e-01    2.8108e+05 ;     C1 - H3
```

**Desired output file:**

```
[ atomtypes ]
;name   bond_type     mass     charge   ptype   sigma         epsilon       Amb
 c3       c3          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.39967e-01   4.57730e-01 ; 1.91  0.1094
 n3       n3          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.25000e-01   7.11280e-01 ; 1.82  0.1700
 h1       h1          0.00000  0.00000   A     2.47135e-01   6.56888e-02 ; 1.39  0.0157
 hn       hn          0.00000  0.00000   A     1.06908e-01   6.56888e-02 ; 0.60  0.0157

[ moleculetype ]
;name            nrexcl
 MOL              3

[ atoms ]
;   nr  type  resi  res  atom  cgnr     charge      mass       ; qtot   bond_type
     1   c3     1   MOL    C1    1     0.152200     36.03000 ; qtot 0.152 ;edited
     2   n3     1   MOL    N1    2    -0.723601     52.03000 ; qtot -0.571 ;edited
     3   c3     1   MOL    C2    3     0.163500     36.03000 ; qtot -0.408 ;edited
     4   c3     1   MOL    C3    4     0.161900     36.03000 ; qtot -0.246 ;edited
     5   n3     1   MOL    N2    5    -0.820001     52.03000 ; qtot -1.066 ;edited
[ bonds ]
;   ai     aj funct   r             k
     1      2   1    1.4700e-01    2.6828e+05 ;     C1 - N1    
     1      8   1    1.0930e-01    2.8108e+05 ;     C1 - H1    
     1      9   1    1.0930e-01    2.8108e+05 ;     C1 - H2    
     1     10   1    1.0930e-01    2.8108e+05 ;     C1 - H3
```

Comment: check `len()` before accessing a specific index

Comment: Does this filetype have a name?  `line` is a line from the file, so `atom` is going to be a single character.  You can't split a single character into eight pieces

Comment: Input file type is top file format (http://manual.gromacs.org/online/top.html). It doesn't matter. The question is that how can I get the desired output file?